# Считать файл, произвести операцию с данными и безопасно записать строку файл PHP

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток! Скажу сразу, я новичок и проблема несложная, но я хочу найти короткое, простое, надёжное решение. Знаю, похожих тем много, но прошу на пальцах объяснить мне конкретный пример. Вот у меня скрипт go.php на который шлю траффик, он должен сделать кое-какие проверки и если нужно, то открыть файл или создать его, если нет, считать содержимое, добавить переход юзера, и передиректить на index.php. Весь код приводить не буду ибо проблема с записью (при быстром сливе трафа (около 10 запросов в сек.) файл обнуляется.

```
        if (file_exists("traffic.txt")) { 
            $get_traffic = file_get_contents("traffic.txt"); 
            $new_traffic = $get_traffic + 1; // Добавляем ещё 1 переход
            file_put_contents("traffic.txt", $new_traffic, LOCK_EX); // Записываем строку (новое значение переходов) в файл с блокировкой доступа
        } 
        else {
            file_put_contents("traffic.txt", "1", LOCK_EX); // Записываем строку (первый переход) в файл с блокировкой доступа
        }
```

Это короче чем fopen, flock, fwrite, fclose. Но, LOCK_EX не работает, что не так, что добавить сюда или как надо. Только хотелось бы самый короткий правильный вариант, но, чтобы без косяков.

Comment: Он и не будет работать в такой ситуации. В момент чтения ведь вы блокировку не берете. значит с момента чтения до записи с файлом может произойти что угодно. кроме того file_put_contents берет блокировку после того как открыл файл и усек его до 0 длины. и кто то может успеть проcкочить в момент между тем как он его отрыл и очистил и тем как он взял блокировку

Comment: Ох уж эти блогеры... пишут, что так безопасно... Моя любимая функция была, а случайно заметил, что что-то идёт не так... Научите, как правильно, чтобы избежать такой ситуации?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.flock.php пример там посмотрите. перед очисткой как раз можно вставить чтение текущего значения. Вообще можно было бы воспользоваться БД. но если у вас действительно всего одно значение, то возможно так проще.

Comment: Как раз смотрю уже. Можете здесь готовый код написать, как должно быть, чтобы мне не напортачить?

Answer (score 0):

Так правильно будет?

```
if (file_exists("traffic.txt")) { 
$fp = fopen("traffic.txt", "w");
    if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) { 
        $get_traffic = fread($fp); 
        $new_traffic = $get_traffic + 1; 
        fwrite($fp, $new_traffic);
        fflush($fp);
        flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
    } else {
    header("location: /go.php");
    }
fclose($fp);
}

else {
 $fp = fopen("traffic.txt", "w+");
    if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {
        fwrite($fp, "1");
        fflush($fp);
        flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
    } else {
    header("location: /go.php");
    }
fclose($fp);
}
```